# Significance of wave number?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, acoustics

Till now all I know about the wave number is its formula i.e. ${\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}}$. I always wanted to know what it really means. So can anyone please, explain me its physical significance?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Imagine something oscillating in space and time, for example a plane wave propagating along the axis $x$. This propagation is expressed via the so-called  *phase*
$$
\phi(x,t)=\omega \cdot t - k\cdot x = \dfrac{2\pi}{T}\cdot t -\dfrac{2\pi}{\lambda}\cdot x
\tag{01}
$$
and the magnitude of the plane wave as
$$
E(x,t)=A\cos\phi(x,t)
\tag{02}
$$
As the **frequency in time** $\:\nu=1/T \:$ gives how many cycles are executed by $E(x_{0},t)$ *per unit time $t$ at a specific space point*  $x_{0}$, so the **frequency in space** $\:1/\lambda \:$ gives how many cycles are executed by $E(x,t_{0})$ *per unit length in space $x$ at a specific time moment*  $t_{0}$.

**EDIT**
Both frequencies and consequently the phase (01) are expressed as angles in radian units. A full cycle is a
$2\pi $ radians angle.  That's why this factor in $\omega=2\pi / T$ and $k=2\pi / \lambda$.
\begin{align}
T  \equiv & \text{time  length for a full cycle of the phase at given space point = period} \tag{03a}\\
                &\phi(x,t+T)  =\phi(x,t)+2\pi  \tag{03b}\\
\lambda  \equiv & \text{space length for a full cycle of the phase at given time moment = wavelegth} \tag{04a}\\
                & \phi(x+\lambda,t) =\phi(x,t)-2\pi  \tag{04b}
\end{align}

Comment: I not forgot...always very nice your explanations.

Comment: @Sebastiano : Welcome...

Comment: In Italian textbooks translated some from English the wave number $k$ is the number of oscillations per unit length (wavelength). Is it the same?

Comment: @Sebastiano : Essentially $1/\lambda$ is  the number of oscillations per unit length. The wave number $k=2\pi/\lambda$ is its $""$conversion$""$ in angle radians per unit lenght. Consider that to a complete oscillation corresponds an angle of $2\pi$ that is a complete circle. By the way, which Italian book ???

Answer (score 2):

Basically it is whatever you need to multiply a distance by to find a phase difference (in radians).

For a traveling wave, the wave number is the amount of phase difference per unit length.

For a physical sine wave, it is the ratio between the maximal slope of the wave surface and the amplitude. In other words, it measures how dramatic the *local differences* in displacement can be, relative to the maximal *absolute* displacement.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers already explain
the wave-number as the phase difference per length.
Therefore I only elaborate on the 3-dimensional properties of the wave-number.

Unlike the wavelength $\lambda$
the wave-number ($k=2\pi/\lambda$) can be regarded as a vector.
To understand this consider the image below, showing a plane wave.
(I show only in 2 dimensions, because it is easier to draw.
But you can do the same reasoning also in 3 dimensions.)

[image: wave]

The wave has wavelength $\lambda$.
Along the $x$-direction it has a wavelength $\lambda_x$,
and likewise, along the $y$-direction a wavelength $\lambda_y$.
Notice also that $\lambda_x\ge\lambda$ and $\lambda_y\ge\lambda$.

We see, the Pythagorean relation is not true:
$$\lambda^2\ne\lambda_x^2+\lambda_y^2+\lambda_z^2$$

But we have a somewhat similar relation for the reciprocals
(see also the [Inverse Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Pythagorean_theorem)):
$$\frac{1}{\lambda^2}=\frac{1}{\lambda_x^2}+\frac{1}{\lambda_y^2}+\frac{1}{\lambda_z^2}$$

It can be shown that the 3 components $(1/\lambda_x,1/\lambda_y,1/\lambda_z)$
have all properties of a [vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(mathematics_and_physics)), including the transformation behavior
when rotating the $xyz$ coordinate system.

The wave number vector is defined as
$$\vec{k}
= \begin{pmatrix} k_x \\ k_y \\ k_z \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} 2\pi/\lambda_x \\ 2\pi/\lambda_y \\ 2\pi/\lambda_z \end{pmatrix}$$
Its direction is perpendicular to the wave fronts.
This definition includes the factor $2\pi$
($=360°$) just for convenience,
so that $\vec{k}$ gives the phase difference per length,
rather than the number of waves per length.
Hence the phase difference between two positions separated by $\Delta\vec{r}$
can be calculated by the scalar product
$$\Delta\phi=\vec{k}\cdot\Delta\vec{r}.$$