# Is temporal wavelength of a wave always equivalent to its spatial wavelength?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, wavelength

I can't see how it would be possible for these two to be different.

Comment: What do you mean by "temporal wavelength"? Please improve the wording of your question.

Comment: @freecharly do you know what temporal frequency is? It seems like the other answerers know what I'm talking about.

Comment: This only shows that  the answerers (myself included) are good in guessing this time. You should use commonly used technical terms when posing questions here. This can only help you to also obtain good answers. That your idiosyncratic terminology is not not conducive to understanding your questions is also reflected in the number of closing votes.

Comment: @freecharly The closing votes are only there to serve to indicate your mindset to close every question you dislike. Plenty of closed good questions do not even fall into the category they are closed in.

Comment: @freecharly Also instead of commenting this, you could've just told me what the correct technical terminology is.

Comment: I am sorry that you have this (unwarranted) impression. You can find the correct terminology in my answer below. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For spatial, it is the number of occurrences per unit-distance.

For temporal it is per unit-time.

Yes they can be different.

Please see here:

[Significance of wave number?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/265008/significance-of-wave-number/265022#265022)

> Both frequencies and consequently the phase (01) are expressed as angles in radian units. A full cycle is a 
>   $2\pi $ radians angle.  That's why this factor in $\omega=2\pi / T$ and $k=2\pi / \lambda$.
>   \begin{align}
> T  \equiv & \text{time  length for a full cycle of the phase at given space point = period} \tag{03a}\\
>                 &\phi(x,t+T)  =\phi(x,t)+2\pi  \tag{03b}\\
> \lambda  \equiv & \text{space length for a full cycle of the phase at given time moment = wavelegth} \tag{04a}\\
>                 & \phi(x+\lambda,t) =\phi(x,t)-2\pi  \tag{04b}
> \end{align}

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the term "temporal wavelength" is used in physics. It is the first time that I see it. Wavelength is defined for a spatially periodic wave pattern corresponding to a periodic signal in time at a given location. The time interval corresponding to a spatial wavelength of a periodic wave is usually called period $T$ and is related to the frequency $f$ and wavelength $\lambda$ by $$T=\frac {1}{f}=\frac {\lambda}{v}$$ where $v$ is the wave velocity.

Thus there is always a correspondence between the spatial wavelength $\lambda$ and the time period $T$ of a periodic wave.