# Wave explanation and derivation

Tags: waves, fourier-transform, dispersion

Why must the term $kx-\omega t$ be constant? I mean from an intuitive point of view.
I can mathematically prove it, however I don't seem to understand it very well.

Comment: Can your little further explain what you are asking?

Comment: It doesn't have to be constant unless you are interested in the behavior of a point of constant phase.  For example, if you want to know the phase velocity of a wave, you would follow a point of constant phase ... say, a peak or a zero crossing (or any other [constant] value of phase).

Answer (score 1):

This is the phase $\phi=\left(kx-\omega t\right)$ of a wave. If you follow a point moving so that the phase on it to be constant, that is $\phi=\left(kx-\omega t\right)=\texttt{constant}$, then $\mathrm d\phi=\left(k\mathrm dx-\omega \mathrm d t\right)=0$ so the wave is propagating with speed $\upsilon_{ph}=\mathrm dx/\mathrm d t=\omega/k$.

---

Related : [Significance of wave number](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/265008/significance-of-wave-number/265022#265022).