# Can you explain me the definition of wave number as defined in theoretical physics?

Tags: waves, momentum, terminology, definition, wavelength

**[Wavenumber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavenumber), as used in spectroscopy and most chemistry fields, is defined as the number of wavelengths per unit distance**.

The corresponding formula is

$$k=\frac{1}{\lambda}.$$

**However, in theoretical physics, a wave number defined as the number of radians per unit distance and the formula is** $$k=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}.$$

Should not the definition used in physics be number of wavelengths per unit radian? If not then why?

Comment: Duplicate : [Significance of wave number?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/265008/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Significance of wave number?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/265008/)

Comment: Perhaps I'm mistaken, but I understood the question to be, not about the significance of the wave number, but about the fact that there are two definitions.

Comment: It comes down to whether you want plane waves to be $\exp2\pi ikx$ or $\exp ikx$.

Answer (score 0):

It may vary from language to language, but in mine (French) a similar confusion exists. Both $1/\lambda$ and $2\pi/\lambda$ are called "wave number", although they aren't the same thing (the former in a frequency, the latter an angular frequency).

Although they have the same dimension (inverse length), they also have different units ($\text{m}^{-1}$ vs $\text{rad.m}^{-1}$).

It's annoying that they're called the same. However, $1/\lambda$ seems to be very rarely used outside MRI. Just difference in habits.