# What is $k$ in this form of the wave equation?

Tags: waves, electric-fields, vectors

I have just been introduced to the concept of waves and I found this wave equation for an electromagnetic wave in a book. I don't understand what is $\vec{k}$ here.

$\vec{E}$ = $E°\vec{n}cos(\vec{k}.\vec{r})$

I don't think it is wave number since that can't be a vector. Kindly help! :)

Comment: Related : [Significance of wave number?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/265008/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a static field, so not really a wave. This however:
$$\vec{E}=E_0\vec{n}\,\cos(\omega t-\vec{k}.\vec{r})$$
is a wave. $\vec{k}$ is called the wavevector:

- its norm is the wave number
- its direction is the direction of propagation

Take for example $\vec{k}=k\,\hat{x}$ and let $c=k/\omega$. Then:
$$\vec{E}=E_0\vec{n}\,\cos(\omega t-kx)$$
This expression is invariant under $x\to x+l$ and $t\to t+l/c$ for any $l$, which means that this field propagates at velocity $c$ in the direction $x$.