# What's (intuitively) the $k$ in the de Broglie formula?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, momentum, wavelength

Background: I'm currently doing self-study of quantum physics by following university level quantum physics lectures on YouTube (e.g. the YouTube *MIT 8.04 Quantum Physics I, Spring 2013* or *Stanford Quantum Lectures by Leonhard Susskind*, plus supplemental YouTube courses like DrPhysicsA, with the occasional popular level YouTube on specific subjects). My classic math and physics is somewhat robust (high-school) but rusty (about 30 years ago).

In one of the MIT lectures I came about the de Broglie formulas:

[image: de Broglie].

I did google and kind of understand how the de Broglie idea for wavelength lambda is determined for a particle with a certain mass (somewhat analog to the Einstein formula for photons) p= h/lambda and then lambda= h/p and then going classic on p via mass*velocity.

However, in the lecture the professor is using $k$ and refers to $k$ as as the wave-number (in conjunction with the reduced Planck constant).

$p = \hbar k $ with

$ k = \frac {2 \pi} \lambda $

So I guess, in intuitive terms (maybe this question is due to my rusty knowledge of classic physics), what's best way to think of $k$?  Or maybe someone can just point me to a lecture/explanation of $k$ in terms of classic waves.

Comment: Similar question: [Significance of wave number?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/265008/)

Comment: Related : [About de Broglie relations, what exactly is E? Its energy of what?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/257826/about-de-broglie-relations-what-exactly-is-e-its-energy-of-what/258207#258207).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply a measure of wavelength. Wavelength ($\lambda$) should be reasonably intuitive. The reason we use $k$ is simply that formulae involving $\lambda$ tend to be cluttered with factors of $2\pi$. Using $k$ leads to less clutter. But every such formula may be written in $\lambda$ terms.

Comment: Oh, so (crudely speaking since your explanation just pulls the $k$ to the edge of my intuition, which is awesome anyway), since the $cos$ and $sin$ functions always involve some $2\pi$, it's a way to just get the $2\pi$ out of the way by help with using $\hbar$ instead of $h$ ?  Crudely (intuitively speaking), a bit like making $cos$ being based on 1 for a full cycle, instead of $2\pi$ or 360°, so you don't all the time have to divide or multiply by $2\pi$?

Comment: @Terminality Yes, Also putting $k$ in numerators where it's handier than $\lambda$ in denominators. As emir sezik points out, that makes it useful as a vector.

Comment: Awesome. Your answer led me on the right track (also after writing my first comment  I recognized that $h$ ist a constant and $2\pi$ is a constant, so  $\hbar$ is just a way to pull out the 2*pi from equations that would otherwise  contain it (as you said: decluttering). Very cool. 

Answer (score 1):

$k$ is the spatial frequency of the periodic wavefunction for the particle represented in angular as opposed to cyclic units. In cyclic units the spatial frequency is $\nu = k/2\pi = 1/\lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add something to Jagerber's answer as $k$ is very useful even in classical waves. $\vec{k}$ also tells the direction of propagation in the waves.

First consider a monochromatic wave traveling in 1-D. Intuitively we should use a periodic function to describe the amplitude of a periodic wave wave! The simplest function is

$$\psi = Asin(bx)\tag{1}$$

where $\psi$ is the amplitude of the wave. Note we can deduce the value of b by realising that the wave should be periodic in its wavelength, i.e $\psi(x) = \psi(x+\lambda)$. This just means that after traveling one wavelength, we should come to the same point in the wave. Using equation (1), we have

$$ sin(bx) = sin(bx+ b\lambda)$$

Using the fact that $sin(\theta) = \sin(\theta +2 \pi)$, we deduce that

$$b \equiv k = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$$

Therefore, we have a definition for the $\textbf{wavevector}$ $k$. Now let's move on to $3$-D to see what it corresponds to then.

Consider again a monochromatic wave emanating from a single source at some point in space. The amplitude is given by

$$ \psi \sim \frac{ e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{x} }}{r}$$

where the $1/r$ power fall-off ensures energy conservation. In $3$-D, we can talk about contours of constant amplitude. Consider sitting at a point $\vec{x}$ and displacing it slightly by some vector $\delta\vec{x}$. If we are to have the same amplitude, we must have $\vec{k} \cdot \delta\vec{x} = 0$. This means that vector $\vec{k}$ tells you the direction in which the magnitude increases. Another way to see this is to compute $\nabla \psi$ and show that it is proportional to $\vec{k}$. Therefore, $\vec{k}$ also tells you the direction of propagation of the wave!

Hope this helps.

$\textbf{EDIT:}$

I forgot to add the connection with QM. The reason why $\vec{p} = \hbar \vec{k}$ makes sense is the last paragraph. The momentum of the wavepacket is in the direction of the propagation!