# Why temporal and spatial term is multiplied to get the wave equation?

Tags: waves, spacetime, fourier-transform

When deriving the wave equation we have:
$$y_{spatial} = A\exp(ikx)$$
$$y_{temporal} = A\exp(-i\omega t).$$

Then the overall wave equation is obtained by multiplying both time and spatial component. But why multiplication gives us the wave equation? what is the mathematical proof that their multiplication is going to give us the wave equation?

Comment: just draw in an (x,t) diagram either the real or the imaginary part of the function, it is a sinusoidal wave. Have you heard of Euler's fomula?

Comment: Note: This is not what is commonly referred to as the wave equation. (As this is tagged "Schrödiger equation": Even though the unknown in the Schrödinger function is called the wave-function, the Schrödinger equation is not a/the wave equation either). [Wikipedia on the wave equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation).

Comment: Related by a second glance  : [Significance of wave number?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/265008/significance-of-wave-number/265022#265022).

Comment: Any function of the form $f(kx\pm\omega t$ is a solution of the wave equation and hence so is your product $y_{\rm spatial}\times y_{\rm temporal}$.

Comment: We do not multiply the spatial and time dependence of the wave (it would give a factor $A^2$). We multiply only the phases.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 Quite right but I will have to leave my comment as it is as I cannot edit it and with your comment the "correction" is made.